# Which choice of technology for this?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql

I face the following problem.
The target is to develop a DB to store the following schema:

You have  `PRODUCTS` that can be composed of both `PRIMARY_PRODUCTS` and also other `PRODUCTS`.

My first question is to know which one of SQL DB or NoSQL technology would be recommended for this?
I don't really know well NoSQL and I am not sure it is worth spending time investigating if the whole concept is not suited with the pb.
If NoSQL is worth looking at, which version is recommended? I was looking at Cassandra but there are so many types that the universe is quite big.

If NoSQL is not suited for this, so we need to revert to SQL.
Do you thing that `hierarchyId` is suited?

Comment: Could you give an example of the data you want to store? like how it would look etc.

Comment: Do you want to handle transactions? How many records will you have (and how many gigabytes of data)? How many concurrent users will you have?

Comment: Datas to be stored are not complex at all. I will be an int key towards another table.

Answer (score 0):

Both SQL or NoSQL can store and retrieve data of this kind, and both technologies can be made to do this job.

The major differences are elsewhere: in a nutshell, transactions and guaranteed consistency for SQL versus high performance for readers for NoSQL.

In your precise situation SQL, with its support for transactions, will ensure that viewers will see a composite product when all sub-products have been successfully stored.

In most real-life situations, however, the chance of a viewer seeing a partially-committed product on a NoSQL system is so slim as to be irrelevant: future reads of the product will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. In SQL I am a bit messy to which kind of datatype you would use:  I would create a PRODUCTS table and a PRODUCTS_DATA table. I have no idea how to choose the type of the  column in order to be either a PRODUCTS id or a PRIMARY_PRODUCT Id. One solution I can see is to add a column with the type to search but it sounds quick and dirty to me. Any elegant solution?                            In NoSQL in the meantime I have no clue how to do. Any interesting link?